# Save multiple outlook emails individually (same subject lines)

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I'm trying to save off a large archive folder of emails (individually). However, when I drag the contents of the folder to a folder outside of Outlook, any emails with the same subject line are being overwritten.

so I'm going from 300+ emails to 46, because there were emails with a lot of back and forth that have the same subject line.

How would I save off individual emails, without doing it one at a time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you drag (or copy) all of the emails at the same time, any emails with the same subject should automatically be renamed, eg; `Subject (1).msg`, `Subject (2).msg`

This works with Outlook 2010 on Windows 7 anyway.

If your emails are spread through multiple Outlook folders, you could make it simpler by assigning them to a category, and then creating a Search Folder. This would enable you to select all emails at once and copy them.

If you can't save all of the emails at the same time, and have to do it in batches, then try using a utility to automatically rename the files after each batch saved.

For example, you could save a batch of emails, and then use [Ant Renamer](http://www.antp.be/software/renamer) to add a random number to the end of every file name. This will prevent any conflicts if any emails in the next batch have the same subject.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work that way for me - Outlook 2010 Professional Plus Win 7.

Comment: Only seemed to work after I moved the emails from a nested archive directory into their own directory.

Comment: Glad you managed to make it work. I have just updated my answer with idea to make it easier to copy them all at once.

Comment: Posting to confirm this works in Outlook 2010 in Windows 10.